# Sql server View with while statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop

I`m learning to use SQL and this is my second question, hope it make sense! :)

My problem:

When I check a customer’s order, I need to know If it would be fully allocated (pre-shipped ) or not.
The DB hasn’t the progression of the allocated quantity, but only the allocated quantity for each order, and the total ordered to-be-allocated from the customers.
The orders will be allocated by: order priority, confirmation date, internal order number.

This is where I get so far:

```
SELECT dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Item, dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Description,
       dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Qty, dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Allocated,
       CASE WHEN dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Allocated > dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.DeliveredQty
                THEN dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Qty - dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.DeliveredQty - dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Allocated
            ELSE dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Qty - dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.DeliveredQty END AS TOALLOCATE,
       dbo.MA_SaleOrd.InternalOrdNo, dbo.MA_SaleOrd.ConfirmedDeliveryDate,
       dbo.MA_SaleOrd.Customer, dbo.MA_SaleOrd.Priority,
       dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.SaleOrdId, dbo.MA_SaleOrdShipping.Carrier1,
       dbo.MA_SaleOrdShipping.ShipToAddress,
       dbo.MA_ItemsFiscalData.FinalOnHand AS InitialAvailability 
FROM dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails
    INNER JOIN dbo.MA_SaleOrd
      ON dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.SaleOrdId = dbo.MA_SaleOrd.SaleOrdId
    INNER JOIN dbo.MA_SaleOrdShipping
      ON dbo.MA_SaleOrd.SaleOrdId = dbo.MA_SaleOrdShipping.SaleOrdId
    INNER JOIN dbo.MA_ItemsFiscalData
      ON dbo.MA_ItemsFiscalData.Item = dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Item
WHERE (dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Delivered = '0')
  AND (dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Invoiced = '0')
  AND (dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Cancelled = '0')
  AND (dbo.MA_ItemsFiscalData.FiscalYear = YEAR(GETDATE()))
ORDER BY dbo.MA_SaleOrdDetails.Item, dbo.MA_SaleOrd.Priority,
         dbo.MA_SaleOrd.ConfirmedDeliveryDate, dbo.MA_SaleOrd.InternalOrdNo
```

Now I want  to calculate at each row in a new column named “progression” the progression of the quantity that will be allocated.

The progression should be:
For the first listed item = InitialAvailability – TOALLOCATE
For every row with same item = previous TOALLOCATE – TOALLOCATE
And restart every item change

I’ve tried with a WHILE statement but I could not make it work.
Im all yours :)

Comment: Read about Aggregation functions, I think you need `SUM` with an `OVER` clause.

Comment: Check out running totals at the link below - and also clean up your code a little with aliases to make things clearer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server